# understanding of how to get Bootstrap Nav working with additional content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

So I am trying to do some basic prototyping with Bootstrap 3.3.2 and seem to be having some technical changes.  I am able to get the top and bottom nav bars to display correctly, but the content in the middle does not display right when I use anything other than .

Here is the code that works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Company Home Page</title>
    <link id="bootstrapTheme" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.2/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <!-- Header -->
       <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
      <!-- Header -->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
          <div class="navbar-inner navbar-content-center">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The following is the code that I want, but does not seem to work.  The content of the middle seems to end up at the very top of the page behind the navbar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Company Home Page</title>
    <link id="bootstrapTheme" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.2/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <!-- Header -->
       <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
      <div class="container">
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
      <!-- Header -->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
          <div class="navbar-inner navbar-content-center">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The only real change is the replacement of the jumbotron class with the container class.

Any help resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Richard

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  It appears that I needed to wrap my middle section in another .